# spring-neo4j throws exception when saves entity - Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax

Tags: neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j-4

i have a simple spring-neo4j project and only saves an entity. It works in windows 7 that neo4j server is started in localhost. But when i tried in another two machine(neo4j is started in localhost again) it fails with "Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher "Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax". First machine is an English Windows 7 64 bit and others are Turkish Windows 7 64 bit(one is windows server). Does machine language cause that ?

DemoApplication:

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.rest.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com")
public class DemoApplication extends Neo4jConfiguration implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("com.rest.model");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    }
}

...and in spring controller...
@Autowired
private Session session;
..
session.save(object);
..
```

Comment: Could you send us the Cypher statement generated by SDN? You'll find this if you turn on logging for the org.neo4j.ogm package?

Comment: Spring posts: Thread 25: request {"statements":[{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`User`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as nodeRef, ID(n) as nodeId","parameters":{"rows":[{"nodeRef":-827191182,"props":{"name":"sezer"}}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}

Comment: Are you able to execute this statement directly using the Neo4j REST API?

Comment: i'm new in neo4j so couldn't run from web ui, but i run it from advanced rest client and gives this error: "Unknown function 'ID' (line 1, column 87 (offset: 86)) "UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`User`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as nodeRef, ID(n) as nodeId" ^". Also same query is successfully executed in other neo4j server that runs in another machine both of them are 2.3.3 version.

Comment: also id(n) is working, seems to be a system language problem